# How to select by relationship from other model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have tow tables :

> ***products : id, title ,price, created_at, updated_at

This stocks products.

> ***product_details : id, product_id,sell, created_at, updated_at

This stocks numbers of sell for each day.
example

products:

> -----1-product 1- 2.9 -  created_at, updated_at
>
> -----2-product 2- 3.94 -  created_at, updated_at
>
> -----3-product 3- 1.94 -  created_at, updated_at

product_details :

> -----1-2- 3 -  created_at, updated_at
>
> -----2-1- 6 -  created_at, updated_at
>
> -----3-3- 8 -  created_at, updated_at
>
> -----4-2- 6 -  created_at, updated_at
>
> -----5-1- 7 -  created_at, updated_at
>
> -----6-3- 11 -  created_at, updated_at

I have two models:

Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{    
    public function product_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product_detail');
    }
}
```

Product_detail

```
class Product_detail extends Model
{
    //
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
class Test extends Controller
{
    //*
    public function index()
    {
        $products = new Product;

        $today = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();;
        $yesterday = Carbon::now()->subDays(100)->toDateTimeString();
        $products = $products->product_details()->whereBetween('sell', array(1, 90000))->whereBetween('created_at', array($yesterday, $today))->get();
        dd($products);
        }
}
```

I want to select products with the last day sell between 5 and 8.

Further I want select the products with the last day sell between 5, 8 and the created_at between two dates all this informations from Product_detail.

I tried to test with different code to make it, but I failed.

Comment: Check this for further question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda it is for readable if you mark your database like that

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a simple query using Eloquent helper function:

```
Product::whereBetween('date', [$dateOne, $dateTwo])->get();
```

You could also try this if you like that more:

```
Product::where('date_one','<=',$dateOne)
       ->where('date_two','>=',$dateTwo)
       ->get();
```

`->get();` will return all the results, `->first()` will return the first result if you need that.

Of course you need to put the correct variable inside this query, since you did not show us the table names.

Comment: thanks for answer but in need information from other table product_deatail the last one in it with the filter by number and date

Comment: @cha7ta then just modify the query edit the table name and instead of `->get()` you use `->last()` easy peasy lemon squeezy

Comment: whene i use this  code:
Product::where('date_one','<=',$dateOne)
       ->where('date_two','>=',$dateTwo)
       ->get();
i get informationsfrom product when date is between two dates, i need to get the last one from product_detail if is it in condition

Comment: In what conditions, try to use `->last()` instead of `->get()`

Comment: I try it but nothing
I want to select product when last sell between 4 and 9
so the condition will be applicated in product_detail

Comment: @cha7ta you have to modify the query to your needs and then call the last method on it can you post what your query looks like and what the return looks like

Comment: i try this 
$products = $products->product_details_1()->whereBetween('sell', array(1, 8))
             ->whereBetween('created_at', array($yesterday, $today));
but nothing

Comment: Try this `$products = $products->product_details_1()->whereBetween('sell', array(1, 8)) ->whereBetween('created_at', array($yesterday, $today))->last();` Without `->last()` or `->get()` it won't return a result.

Comment: with last:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::last()

with get:
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )

Comment: I use print_r($products); to see what in

Comment: @cha7ta I am out for now I can help in 10 hours again, I would advice to use `dd($products)` looks better, and please add your controller code to your question so I can have a look tomorrow